# mysql 30 days range selection from column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

Each customer have their own billing cycle of 30 days starting from their predefined billing_cycle_day (say billing_cycle_day is 7 th of October then their billing cycle would be 7th Oct to 6th Nov and so forth for every month..)

```
//kilowatts : double
//report_date : timestamp
//billing_cycle_day : int

SELECT sum(m.kilowatts), DAY(m.report_date),  d.billing_cycle_day
FROM reports_month m
join device d on m.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
where m.mobile_number = '123' 
GROUP BY DAY(m.report_date)
```

This gives the total kilowatt usage for each day for all available records grouped by day. Now what I want is to limit it to the billing cycle of each customer....

I tried using

```
SELECT sum(m.kilowatts), DAY(m.report_date),  d.billing_cycle_day
FROM reports_month m
join device d on m.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
where m.mobile_number = '123'
and DAY(m.report_date) BETWEEN d.billing_cycle_day AND d.billing_cycle_day + INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY DAY(m.report_date)
```

and lots of variations of the functions.Do I have to go for a stored proc then pls help me on that.

But still no luck,,,,
Any help would be strongly appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATE_ADD:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

```
SELECT sum(m.kilowatts), DAY(m.report_date),  d.billing_cycle_day
FROM reports_month m
JOIN device d on m.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
WHERE m.mobile_number = '123'
AND DAY(m.report_date) BETWEEN d.billing_cycle_day AND DATE_ADD(d.billing_cycle_day, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(m.report_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the date test in the `ON` clause, since it's part of the relationship between the two tables. And don't use the `DAY()` function in the comparison, since it just returns the a number like 13 for November 13 (what does it mean to ask if 13 is between 7 October and 7 November?); you want to compare the whole date.

```
SELECT sum(m.kilowatts), DAY(m.report_date),  d.billing_cycle_day
FROM reports_month m
join device d
on m.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
   and m.report_date BETWEEN d.billing_cycle_day AND d.billing_cycle_day + INTERVAL 30 DAY
where m.mobile_number = '123'    
GROUP BY DAY(m.report_date)
```